# load models in different controller cakephp performance

Tags: performance, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

Suppose I have these models - Post, Category, User. Post belongsTo Category and User.

In my PostsController inside some action I want to get data from categories or users table I can use one of the following

```
1) public $uses = array('Post', 'Category', 'User') and use Category model like
$this->Category->find('all'); everywhere in that controller

2)  $this->Post->Category ->find('all');

3)  $this->loadModel('Category '), than use 
    $this->Category->find('all') in that action
```

So, my question is which one of these will have the best performance and why ? Maybe for small applications it won't have any visible effect, but what if the project is big and there are dozens of models that should be used in the same controller and every little performance improvement does matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the association in the model, use that (#2). This makes sense because these models would most likely already be loaded (if you're not caching).

Otherwise, use the `loadModel` function. This way you'll be loading the model only when you need it. Either way, unless you have some major work going on in your constructors (you shouldn't), it really won't matter that much.

Comment: +1 though in 2.3 there's likely no difference at all between any of the options as models are lazy-loaded on first access/reference